# Two tikz figures (with colored areas) next to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs

I would like place to figures/graphs next to each other. So far, I've managed to create the first figure and parts of the second figure. I don't know how to place them next to each other and how to color the different regions of the figures or insert tags inside the areas.

**Desired output:**

[image]

**Curent output**

[image]

**Current code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2,scale=1.2,thick]
    % coordinates path with intersections
\coordinate (O)     at  (0,0);
    % coordinate axes
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (9,0)  node[right] {$Q$};
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (0,6)  node[above] {$P$};
    % line MC
\draw[line width=1mm, purple]
    (0,1) -- + (7.7,0) node[right] {$MC$};
    % line MR
\draw[line width=0.8mm, dashed , black]
    (0,5.7) -- (4,0) node[below] {$MR$};    
    % line D
\draw[line width=0.8mm, black]
    (0,5.7) -- (7,0) node[below] {$D$};
    % line Q
\draw[line width=0.2mm, black]
    (3.3,0) -- + (0,3) node[below] {$Q$};    
    % line P
\draw[line width=0.2mm, black]
    (0,3) -- + (3.3,0) node[left] {$P$};    
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2,scale=1.2,thick]
    % coordinates path with intersections
\coordinate (O)     at  (0,0);
    % coordinate axes
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (9,0)  node[right] {$Q$};
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (0,6)  node[above] {$P$};
    % line MC
\draw[line width=1mm, purple]
    (0,1) -- + (7.7,0) node[right] {$MC$};
    % line P_2
\draw[line width=0.2mm, black]
    (0,3) -- + (3.3,0) node[left] {$P_2$};
    % line P_1
\draw[line width=0.2mm, black]
    (0,2) -- + (4.5,0) node[left] {$P_1$};
    % line Q_2
\draw[line width=0.2mm, black]
    (3.3,0) -- + (0,3) node[below] {$Q_2$};
    % line Q_1
\draw[line width=0.2mm, black]
    (4.5,0) -- + (0,2) node[below] {$Q_1$};    
    % line D_1
\draw[line width=0.8mm, black]
    (0,5.7) -- (7,0) node[below] {$D_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove empty line in code between both pictures. It require to move next picture in new line.

Comment: And use `scale=0.75`. With `scale=1.2` both figures can't fit on a single line.

Comment: Thank you, both. So far the two figures are on the same line. Is it possible to color the different areas?

Answer (score 1):

I finish only left image, the second you can finish on similar way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, scopes}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,
    thick,
L/.style args = {#1/#2}{% L: line
    line width=#1,
    draw = #2 %color
                },
L/.default = 0.8mm/black,
 NS/.style = {%N: Node Shape
    text=black, font=\Large,}
                    ]
    % coordinates path with intersections
\coordinate (O)     at  (0,0);
    % coordinate axes
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (6.5,0)  node[right] {$Q$};
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (0,6.5)  node[above] {$P$};
    % line P -- Q
\draw[densely dotted, fill=orange!80]
    (0,3) node[left] {$P$} -| (3,0) node[below] {$Q$}
                           -| (0,3) node[NS,pos=0.25,above=1mm] {$\pi$};
    % DL area
\fill[gray!30]
    (3,3) -- (6,0) -- node[NS,above=1mm] {DL} (3,0) -- cycle;
    % CS area
\fill[orange!40]
    (0,3) -- node[NS,pos=0.25,above=1mm] {CS} (3,3) -- (0,6) -- cycle;
    % line MC
\draw[L=1mm/purple]
    (0,1) -- + (6,0) node[NS,right] {$MC$};
    % line D
\draw[L]
    (0,6) -- (6,0) node[below] {$D$};
    % line MR
\draw[L, dashed]
    (0,6) -- (3.3,-0.6) node[NS,below] {$MR$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,
    thick,
L/.style args = {#1/#2}{% L: line
    line width=#1,
    draw = #2 %color
                },
L/.default = 0.8mm/black,
 NS/.style = {%N: Node Shape
    text=black, font=\Large,}
                    ]
    % coordinates path with intersections
\coordinate (O)     at  (0,0);
    % coordinate axes
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (6.5,0)  node[right] {$Q$};
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (0,6.5)  node[above] {$P$};
    % line and fill P_2 -- Q_2
\draw[densely dotted, fill=orange!80]
    (0,3) node[left] {$P_2$} -| (3,0) node[below] {$Q_2$}
                             -| (0,3) node[NS,pos=0.25,above=1mm] {$\pi_2$};
    % line and fill P_1 -- Q_1
\fill[orange!80] (3,0) rectangle +(1.5,1.5);
\draw[densely dotted]
    (0,1.5) node[left] {$P_1$} -| (4.5,0) node[below] {$Q_1$}
                               -| (0,1.5) node[NS,pos=0.07,above=1mm] {$\pi_1$};
    % DL area
\fill[gray!30]
    (4.5,1.5) -- (6,0) -- node[NS,above=1mm] {DL} (4.5,0) -- cycle;
    % CS area
% 
% not finished
%
    % line MC
\draw[L=1mm/purple]
    (0,1) -- + (6,0) node[NS,right] {$MC$};
    % line D
\draw[L]
    (0,6) -- (6,0) node[below] {$D$};
    % line MR
\draw[L, dashed]
    (0,6) -- (3.3,-0.6) node[NS,below] {$MR$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Option`showframe` is only for test purposes, that you can see, how images fith text width.

Comment: thank you for your reply. The areas are not quite like in the desired output. The areas go from the purple MC line and above. So the x-coordinates of CS and π go from zero and up till the intersection of the dashed line and the purple line. How would you make the coloring contingent on the intersections?